# find the depth of a networking chain in multimap

Tags: c++, recursion, multimap

I have a program that connects 2 people. The connection is saved to a multimap as key value pair. for e.g `add john tim`  adds tim as a connection to john, tim can add more people and his connections can add more people.

I need to find the depth of a person’s subnetwork, that is, the longest recruitment chain starting from this person. For e.g, given the following set of data

```
> add john mary
> add john tom
> add mary brad
> add tom Maria
> add mary Eli
> add brad Sofia
```

`Depth John` should return 4, because the longest chain `John` has is 4.

`John -> Mary -> Brad -> sofia` (4)

`John -> tom -> Maria` (3)

and `Depth sofia` will return 1, since she's on her own and doesn't extend to anyone.

Here's what I've attempted.

- for each key, find how many exists in the map (using equal_range)
- then iterate through that and for each of them, count their depth
- save the depth as the max and compare it after each iteration and return the max

Here is the code.

```
void count_depth_recursive(std::multimap<std::string, std::string>networkMap, std::string id, int depth)
{
    for(auto itr = networkMap.begin(); itr != networkMap.end(); ++itr)
    {
      if(itr->first == id)
      {
        ++depth;
        count_recursive(networkMap, itr->second, depth);
      }
    }

}
```

Driver function.

```
int count_depth(std::multimap<std::string, std::string>networkMap, std::string id)
{
    int depth = 0;
    int max = 0;
    auto find = networkMap.equal_range(id);
    for(auto itr = find.first; itr != find.second; ++itr)
        count_depth_recursive(networkMap, itr->first, depth);
        std::cout << depth << std::endl;

    return depth;
}
```

I keep getting zero as the answer and I'm starting to doubt if my approach is the right way to go about this.

Comment: `depth` is not modified, because you are passing it by value, use `int& depth`.

Comment: Now it returns 12. When it should be 4. I'm guessing my logic isn't correct.

Comment: @cyberbemon you reuse `depth` on each iteration, which may cause it.

Comment: also you should be aware there may be circle in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a multimap, you can use Adjacency List data structure to represent the graph: `unordered_map<string, vector<string>> Adj` where the vector at `Adj[person]` will represent the direct connections of that person.

After that you can implement this [algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/) to find the longest path for each person. The time complexity of this algorithm is `O(V+E)`.